# How to make the header of the first AvalonDock document invisible

Tags: header, avalondock

The first document of the AvalonDock ist must be always visible and should be not rearranged. How can I set the tab item this document invisible.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a bad idea, no tab means the content cannot be selected.

Comment: I don't think this can currently be implemented/supported in AvalonDock. There is a [CanMove](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/wiki/LayoutDocument#properties) property but this usually applies to all documents of a certain type. So, unless you do some complicated document class conversion whenever a document becomes the first document this one might overly complicated to solve :-(